# How can I remove all words that end in ":" from a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm wondering how to remove a dynamic word from a string within Python.

It will always have a ":" at the end of the word, and sometimes there's more than one within the string. I'd like to remove all occurrences of "word:".

Thanks! :-)

Comment: What is a "dynamic word"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
import re
blah = "word word: monty py: thon"
answer = re.sub(r'\w+:\s?','',blah)
print answer
```

This will also pull out a single optional space after the colon.

Comment: @veb A less intimidating intro to python regular expressions: http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/regex/

Comment: @veb: welcome to SO. If a posted answer is what you're looking for, press the checkmark icon to "accept" it.

Comment: It told me to wait 7 minutes. So I'm waiting. heh

Comment: Ahh okay. Didn't know that limitation; it must be new. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This removes all words which end with a ":":

```
def RemoveDynamicWords(s):
    L = []
    for word in s.split():
        if not word.endswith(':'):
            L.append(word)
    return ' '.join(L)
print RemoveDynamicWords('word: blah')
```

or use a generator expression:

```
print ' '.join(i for i in word.split(' ') if not i.endswith(':'))
```

Comment: @David: that's not a generator expression, that's a list expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ chunk for chunk in line.split() if not chunk.endswith(":") ]
```

this will create a list. you can join them up afterwards.